# How can I add after AND on the duplicate key update?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my mysql query:

```
INSERT INTO TEACHER (FACULTYID,FIRST_NAME,SURNAME) 
  VALUES('17427', 'fn', 'ls') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TEACHERID = TEACHERID, 
                          FACULTYID = FACULTYID, 
                          FIRST_NAME = 'fn', 
                          SURNAME = 'ls' 
                    WHERE FIRST_NAME = 'fn' 
                      AND SURNAME = 'ln'
```

I want to update the values only if the combination of first name and the last name match. How can I do so?

For example,
If i have the following row in my table

```
TeacherID = primary key
FACULTYID = foreign key
FIRST_NAME = unique
SURNAME = unique

TeacherID, FACULTYID, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME
6678        17427      Makram     Bou Nassar
```

And I come along another instance of the same teacher

```
FIRST_NAME = Makram, SURNAME = Bou Nassar.
```

Then I want to abort adding the new tuple, just keep the old one.

Suppose I came along a teacher

```
FIRST_NAME = Makram, SURNAME = OBAJI
then I add a new tuple.
Also add a new tuple when 
FIRST_NAME = Ali, SURNAME = Bou Nassar
```

Comment: It isn't obvious what you want the result to be here. Should neither the first nor last  be updated unless they are not already `fn, ln`? I assume TEACHERID is a PK. Can you show an example of what the original row should look like, and what the updated row should look like, plus an example of a row that should _not_ be modified by the on duplicate key update?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski please check edit

Answer (score 2):

You need a unique index to identify the duplicates.  There is no `where` clause for `on duplicate key`.  So:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_teacher_firstname_surname on teacher(first_name, surname);
```

Note:  You can also do this with a unique constraint (unique constraints are  implemented using unique indexes).

Then:

```
INSERT INTO TEACHER (FACULTYID, FIRST_NAME, SURNAME) 
  VALUES('17427', 'fn', 'ls') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FACULTYID = VALUES(FACULTYID);
```

Notes:

- You don't need to set `first_name` and `surname` because they are already the same.
- You don't need to set `teacherid` because it is not being provided on input.
- The expression `VALUES(FACULTYID)` returns the value being provided for that column.

Comment: thank you for your reply, my problem here is that if we insert a tuple with an different first name and existing last name it does not insert the new tuple, how can i fix that?

Comment: @Predator44 . . . The unique index in this answer uses both the first and last name fields.  Perhaps you have another unique index only on the last name.

Answer (score 0):

Use Update Table. For eg.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```